# JavaScript font-size cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm kind of new to JavaScript. I've created a function that changes the font size and I would like to save the size in a cookie, so that the user won't have to change it every time. But I haven't got the cookie part to work.

I'm using the following libraries: 
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.1 and 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

```
function change_size(element, size) {
var new_size;
var current = parseInt(docCookies.getItem("FontSize"));
if (current !== "") {
    current = parseInt(element.css('font-size'));
}
if (size === 'smaller') {
    if (current > 12) {
        new_size = current - 2;
    }
}
else if (size === 'bigger') {
    if (current < 22) {
        new_size = current + 2;
    }
}
element.css('font-size', new_size + 'px');
docCookies.setItem("FontSize", num.toString(new_size), Infinity);
}

$('#smaller').click(function() {
    change_size($('p'), 'smaller');
});

$('#bigger').click(function() {
    change_size($('p'), 'bigger');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
docCookies.setItem("FontSize", num.toString(new_size), Infinity);
```

to

```
docCookies.setItem("FontSize", new_size, Infinity);
```

You don't have any `num` variable.

Also don't forget to set new font size on page load:

```
var fontSize = docCookies.getItem("FontSize");
if (fontSize) {
    $('p').css('font-size', fontSize + 'px');
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q56wkorw/